# Heavy version of JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I want to render `Swing` over top of LWJGL. It's my understanding that it doesn't work because LWJGL is heavy and most swing components are light. I'm guessing it's an option to put all my `Swing` stuff inside heavy components so they can render on top of it, in the same way a `JPopupMenu` does. Is there something that is basically a heavy version of `JPanel`? Like `JInternalFrame`, but without the top bar, close button, etc, just a simple rectangle? If not, is extending and disabling all the features of a `JInternalFrame` the best choice? (I'm assuming that is doable).

Additional related question: I read somewhere heavy components can't be transparent, does that just mean no translucency? Or does it mean I can't make a doughnut shaped heavy component?

Comment: I think you would just be able to use `Panel` from AWT. I barely use Java any more, but it's my understanding that you can mix AWT and Swing components as of Java 6.

Comment: Just now understanding that JPanel and Panel are separate things, and the J tends to mean its the lightweight equivalent of its AWT equivalent. That explains a lot. I'll try it.

Comment: Yeah, most of the Swing J-Something components have a heavy AWT equivalent.

Comment: Progress report: I put a (non `J`) `Button` in the same `JPanel` as the `Canvas` that LWJGL is rendering into. Didn't work, could never get the `Button` on top. I suspect this is something to do with the way LWJGL draws over the `Canvas` instead of into it. However I put the `Canvas` in a `JDesktopPane` along with a `JInternalFrame`, which rendered on top successfully. Interesting note, apparently which one is top is related to the order they're retrieved by `.getComponents()`. I'll probably just use the JInternalFrame unless someone provides a different idea.

Comment: Also noticed that the "rounded" corners of the `JInternalFrame` weren't really transparent, instead just colored white. Any suggestions about cutting holes in it? Or would I need to make a 4 piece frame in order to form a square doughnut?

Comment: Instead of `JDesktopPane` I used `JLayeredPane` with a `JPanel` which worked. Didn't need to use a `Panel`. Good to go now. Thanks

Comment: LWJGL has it's own rendering process which is (necessarily) compatible with AWT and is undoubtedly incompatible with Swing

Comment: @MadProgrammer The JLayeredPane is doing a lovely job of drawing on top of it.

Comment: @gunfulker Under you current conditions on your current PC ... mixing heavy and lightweight components in AWT/Swing has always caused issues (even though it's suppose to have been fixed). Your intermixing two different rendering process which may not mix well together, just saying

Comment: @MadProgrammer What sort of problems does it cause? Like flickering, wrong thing on top, or sending clicks to the correct panel?

Comment: @gunfulker I've seen flickering, I've seen cross rendering, where the heavy weight component bleeds through the light weigh component and I wouldn't be surprised about events been picked up by the wrong component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95747/discussion-between-gunfulker-and-madprogrammer).